# Method must have a body

Tags: apex, compile-error

I get this error when I try to save the below class. Why? How do I  fix it?

> Error: Method must have a body at line 3 column 27.

```
public class visitController {

    public Sales_Visit__c visit();



    public visitController() {

        visit = new Sales_Visit__c();

    }

    public PageReference save() {

        insert visit;

        visit = new Sales_Visit__c();

        return null;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the parenthesis from `visit()` in the 3rd line. It’s a variable, not a method.